# Implement VideoJS / HolaPlayer with VideoJs Vr

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js, video-player, 360-virtual-reality

My plan is to make HolaPlayer works with VideoJs-Vr plugin but I know I miss something and I want to share with you a part of my code.

First of all, you can see VideoJs & VideoJs-vr working together here:

```
 `https://jsfiddle.net/nvybvl/6hffdf8c/10/`
```

You'll see the error from the issue title.

Second, you can see HolaPlayer (which is an extension of videojs. videojs on steroids as they say)
with VideoJS-Vr here:

```
 `https://jsfiddle.net/nvybvl/6hffdf8c/16/`
```

Both of them isn't working.
I miss something ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you look at console, there is an error. This error can lead you to answer. It is version mismatch. Hola Player use videojs v5 while videojs-vr is on version v6. There is also closed [issue about that](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-vr/issues/38). Maybe there is a videojs-vr release for v5 (you have to find out). Hola Player is just a bundled videojs with many plugins and few customizations. And this is one of cons of these forked bundles. If you want to be on edge, just make your own bundle..